# ¿Cómo obtener el hipervínculo deseado en requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Estoy intentando obtener el hipervínculo de imágenes específicas de BeautifulSoup y requests, con el siguiente código:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pg=requests.post("https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/ps3/mafia-ii/7707#p-37").text

soup= BeautifulSoup(pg)

soup.find_all("img", {"alt":"Portada oficial de Mafia II para PS3"})
```

Sin embargo, esta página cuenta con un selector de plataformas el cual cambia la terminación de el hipervínculo con "p-xx" siendo estas x el id de la plataforma y aunque estoy usando el hipervículo terminando en "#p-37", me está dando el resultado de "#p-41". Obteniendo esto:

```
[<img alt="Portada oficial de Mafia II para PS3" id="imagenportada" itemprop="image" src="https://media.vandal.net/t200/7707/2010121722427_1.jpg" style="width:200px; height:230px;"/>]
```

Cuando el scr debería ser igual a:

```
"https://media.vandal.net/t200/7708/2010121722445_1.jpg"
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para no ser redireccionado a esta plataforma? ¿Cómo puedo interactuar con este selector de plataforma?

Si la pregunta no es lo suficientemente clara, hacérmelo saber, soy nuevo en esta comunidad.

Comment: No creo que solo cambie el ID sino que veo que cambia el número.ero 7707 y 7708

Comment: Así es, tal vez no me expliqué bien, tengo el resto del código, el cual navega entre los diferentes productos y descarga las imágenes, sin embargo siempre descarga sólo la foto de la primer plataforma que aparezca en el selector.